# Using Facebook SDK to upload image to event - Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've created a facebook app, and have been using the Javascript SDK to create events.  My problem is that I can't get it to attach a photo to the event. I've seen examples using the PHP SDK but am wondering if it's possible to do this with **Javascript/JQuery only**?

This is what i've tried, it creates the event but doesn't attach an image:

```
FB.api('/'+userID+'/events', 'post', {
    name:'My Event',
    start_time: startDate,
    end_time: endDate,
    description: 'The test event',
    privacy_type: 'SECRET',
    picture: 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3415/3570338576_c6d4e2d930.jpg'
}, function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }

});
```